# useReducer cannot use object.attr as switch case in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to combine switch case `String` into an object, but somehow typescript is mis-interpreting the switch case in `useReducer`:

### Before version, this works fine:

```
export const LOGIN_USER = "LOGIN_USER";
export const LOGOUT_USER = "LOGOUT_USER";

export type AuthActionType = LogInUser | LogOutUser;

type LogInUser = { type: typeof LOGIN_USER; payload: User }; // <- notice this
type LogOutUser = { type: typeof LOGOUT_USER };

export default function authReducer(
  state: AuthStateType,
  action: AuthActionType
) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGIN_USER: {
      return {
        ...state,
        user: {
          username: action.payload.username, // <- correctly inferring action.payload.username 
          password: action.payload.password
        }
      };
    }

    case LOGOUT_USER: {
      return {
        ...state,
        user: null
      };
    }

    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}
```

### However this breaks, after putting the `switch case` into an object:

```
export const AUTH = {
  LOGIN_USER: "LOGIN_USER",
  LOGOUT_USER: "LOGOUT_USER"
};

export type AuthActionType = LogInUser | LogOutUser;

type LogInUser = { type: typeof AUTH.LOGIN_USER; payload: User };  // <- notice this
type LogOutUser = { type: typeof AUTH.LOGOUT_USER };

export default function authReducer(
  state: AuthStateType,
  action: AuthActionType
) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGIN_USER: {
      return {
        ...state,
        user: {
          username: action.payload.username,  // <- error over here, cannot infer the correct case?
          password: action.payload.password
        }
      };
    }

    case LOGOUT_USER: {
      return {
        ...state,
        user: null
      };
    }

    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}
```

Only by changing the type definition from `type: typeof LOGIN_USER` to `type: typeof AUTH.LOGIN_USER`, typescript breaks the switch case, how's this happenning?

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-hill-jmc1uh?file=/src/App.tsx), please take a look at this minimum reproduced version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use const [assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to let typescript not convert `('LOGIN_USER' to string)`

```
export const AUTH = {
      LOGIN_USER: "LOGIN_USER",
      LOGOUT_USER: "LOGOUT_USER"
    } as const;
```

Comment: Yes! I think that's it, I keep forgetting using assertions, typescript only evalute attribute as string, but not the actual string value.

Answer (score 2):

Change AUTH to an enum

export enum Auth {
LOGIN_USER = “LOGIN_USER”
…code
}

Comment: Can you please explain a bit, why a look up object breaks the switch case?

Comment: I believe your cases don’t exist, they’re undefined in second snippet

Comment: Case should be something like Auth.LOGIN_USER

Comment: I tried using `AUTH.attr` with the after version, it will break somehow.

Answer (score 2):

In the second example you changed the constant values at the top to be an Object of strings where in the first example they are just string constants. I would update the case statements in your second example to match the object:

```
 case AUTH.LOGIN_USER:
   ...
 case AUTH.LOGOUT_USER:
   ...
```

Comment: I tried using `AUTH.attr`, but it breaks nontheless. Somehow string value in an object does not match the case.

Comment: Ah, yes. With type setting a value of typeof you are literally turning the type into the constant value of "string". The other accepted answer should help you around this issue. Good luck!